# Is "With friendship truly," a proper valediction?

Tags: valediction

I want to close a letter with:

With friendship truly,

My Name

For some background; I wrote a letter of recommendations of features to a site, but by my tone it is not extremely clear that I am serious (it's fairly light hearted) and my intentions sincere.  I don't want to say "Sincerely, " because I think it could be over looked or misinterpreted, and I don't want to change my writing style because that would be boring.

It's a weird valediction because it seems like there might be a comma required as in "With friendship, truly,"

Comment: 'Yours sincerely' is the standard British valediction. Everyone, from me, gets that, except my nearest and dearest who  receive varying degrees of 'love' with kisses. But oh how I would have loved to have lived when people said 'I beg to remain your most humble and obedient servant', or some of the French ones, used until recently, such as 'Je vous prie de bien vouloir agréer, Messieurs et Mesdames, l'expression de mes salutations les plus distinguées.  I beg you, ladies and gentlemen, to have the kindness to accept this expression of my most distinguished greetings! Or words to that effect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salutations, valedictions, thanks, and similar bits of etiquette are quite formulaic and generally fall beneath notice. That's problematic if you want to emphasize that you **really** mean it and aren't just being polite. While you can modify the stock phrases to call attention to them, it may end up sounding affected rather than sincere. For example, when somebody says “thank you **so much**,” it may indicate deep gratitude, but more likely it just means that the speaker wants to stand out from the crowd.

Thus, while “with friendship, truly” will probably draw some extra attention, it may not have the implication of sincerity that you're looking for. To express that, put it in the body of the letter, not in the valediction.

Comment: Interesting side note. I just ran into this gem in a survey (I want the ChromeBook cut me some slack): Rating from 0 - 10, where 0 is Unacceptable, 4 is Average, 7 is Outstanding, and 10 is Truly Exceptional. TRULY exceptional.  You better mean it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not *incorrect*, but it sounds rather affected to my ear. You might consider another more conventional but still unusual variation, like "Respectfully".

Comment: I disagree - I think OP's version *is* "incorrect" by any normal definitions of correct/incorrect English. Native speakers would never use it, because they know *truly* (and *ever*) after *Yours* are just "frozen forms" still used to end (relatively) formal letters. Some "creative" variants are of course acceptable *(Yours, in haste)*, but OP's just looks like a bad translation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to articulate sincerity but without using a simple "Sincerely" you could just change how you say it.

> With sincere wishes,
>
> With respectful sincerity,

or something along those lines.